# What differences between certificate private key that retrieved from .pfx file and personal My Store?

Tags: java, certificate, private-key, pfx

I wanna know What differences between certificate private key that retrieved from .pfx file and personal My Store.
I retrieved certificate private key with these two types by using java language.

**retrieved from personal My Store :**

**Private Key** : *RSAPrivateKey [size=2048 bits, type=Exchange, container={DE6E412F-9F87-4E26-8A3A-9C1DAC06A110}]*

**retrieved from .pfx file by user input :**

**Private Key :** *RSA Private CRT Key
            modulus: 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
    public exponent: 10001
   private exponent: 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
             primeP: ddad2933da59cbc2a7129df80e5ddd730ce4711f056fff802699dc12816dcd742a8bcb8bff10acc4eb43bb24dbaf8e3db3b1e026a39a69042907aed105aa344131da0817749ef25d02ce51e34adabede8e4a09b2dae5268b5da4e154939e10a67b2cd9ebe9fcfb93c1c5508dacb2a7d7b4821bc83f97e30d1973e32538bb1b15
             primeQ: e4a1eeb2137558806760445f25f6a90a9450160e153782c0c1ac4b76e63aeec605093764cb02d40a1ab74cdb7180c02e9052c40b7bcb4aafd9e24a4797cda0d5090bf70665ddd55de041bb3d48a0359e28a831a2db77ae5265316b26b3722a52d019c98a8c4e34999f8f90671691d172ea4f4e020f5ce31d70018976621c9ebb
     primeExponentP: 5aa210c58591cf305fb4c9e780a03a096f0cfb7f2e6ef32cc71b831201df0df05ff0d6210001265240ca697a91637ea9958db552b6f34bda8a97fc8eb35d3a8e293eb6ae385d40446d004414c5271880cff64f6ed3f67ac2e25fa64d3929982f290f566e113600fa11708615d6b518d0a599c89820000eb1ed65274ab19e365d
     primeExponentQ: ad7b31e36d605d071169ba777816f1ad555c6f5fc0399ebd2437d80b20271786a9cb947ca68e3ed66bef2a2258bd9915bbed1154a55a5c11930261da711556344fe904479683fca27ec7618bdecfb1df907a0f2fc3d7cc2e391a86739735c9678d00042d5cc8faa096b218a0204004ed6d5d3f93d0946ac0ab7c7f1194e0a29
     crtCoefficient: 7f70f9439d3ab04af8dc5ff8f11fbc60d3e62d5a6220c9421de09374f431214f7cba3cb8eb302c8c79a5c84555c5e29ebec9edc2d1547fd07aea860888a50d5aa1aa2eeb5a40d2f46523bd8fa4125c34dde6a91f9f3c88e9bc3bee484e9367125b20c630fcf2e8144ea31f688a67def228fdcdc02dd6b64e23e0bd67e330c5e6*

Please explain me.

Answer (score 0):

Your private remains the same. You can generate your private key in the Microsoft key store referenced by a key container. When you import your private key from a PFX, the private key gets imported in to the  Microsoft key store byt referenced by the PFX certificate context.